# Perl regexp \A doesn't match start of file?

Tags: regex, perl

I am iterating through a file line by line, picking out lines that start with asterix: `*`. My simple regexp works for all lines except the very first line of the file.

The *DESIRED BEHAVIOR* is: the regexp should correctly match lines that start with an asterix.

The *ACTUAL BEHAVIOR* is: if the asterix occurs on the very first line of the file, the regexp fails to match.

My *DEBUGGING ATTEMPTS* include:

1. Add empty line at start of file. RESULT: The formerly missed line, now at second line of file, is correctly matched by regexp.
2. Remove `\A` from regexp, just match against asterix. The first line of file now correctly is matched by regexp.
3. Try using `^` instead of `\A`. First line of file still fails to match.

*MINIMAL CODE TO REPRODUCE*:

```perl
   while (<$input_fh>) {
     chomp;
     $line = $_;
     if ($line =~ /\A\*/) {
        ...
     }
  }
```

The input file consists of lines of text that may or may not start with an asterix.

Comment: Doesn't you file contain a BOM?

Comment: @choroba interesting idea! But if I change the regex to `/\A.?\*`, it still fails to pick up first line.

Comment: Because a BOM is longer than one byte (the actual number of bytes depends on the encoding).

Comment: Bingo! That was it! Thank you @choroba, `/\A.*?\*/` did the trick. Amazing that I never ran into that before ...

Comment: When you have these problems, inspecting the string with [Data::Dumper](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) or [Devel::Peek](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Data::Peek) can illuminate such problems.

Comment: Data::Dumper with `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` is what you want. (Devel::Peek can help debug XS modules. Not the issue here.)

Comment: You can also use the `perlstring` function from the core `B` module to see what Perl thinks your string is. `use B "perlstring"; printf "read line: %s\n", perlstring $line;`

Answer (score 1):

`/\A\*/` matches start of string, and then an asterisk character.

You need to match any symbols between the start and an asterisk.

Use

```perl
/\A.*?\*/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/YpkUVy/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \A                       the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \*                       '*'
```

Comment: That does't answer the question!